# What is the difference between EntityTypeConfiguration and DbMigration for a new EF project

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Should I use `EntityTypeConfiguration` to build my data model, or should I directly enable migrations an use `DbMigration`.

That is use :

```
public class BlogEFCFConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Blog> {
    public BlogEFCFConfiguration()
        : base() {
        HasKey(x => x.BlogId);
        Property(x => x.BlogId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(128);
    }
}
```

or

```
public partial class InitialCreate : DbMigration {
    public override void Up() {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Blogs",
            c => new
                {
                    BlogId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Name = c.String(maxLength: 128, unicode: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.BlogId);

    }

    public override void Down() {
        DropTable("dbo.Blogs");
    }
}
```

Indeed if I want to change my model I will have to finally use `DbMigration`. So why use `EntityTypeConfiguration` ?

It is may be a too open question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are doing different jobs - EF migrations ensure that the application and database changes are aligned. The configurations inform EF how to map from your object model to your relational model.

Configurations are required when the default conventions don't suit your model.

EF migrations are required if you wish to model the database changes in code between application versions. This has the advantage of being able to automatically have the application update the database to the latest version on startup for example.

Comment: I would like to fully agree, but the fact there is an **Initial** migration that, in fact, is used to create the Db confuses me. By confuse I mean it seems to be a duplication of jobs between Configuration and Migration.

Comment: If you're referring to the automatic creation of the database by code first, then it's not the configuration that does this, it's the database initializer, the default being CreateDatabaseIfNotExists. You probably don't want to run this initializer in production, and if you're using EF migrations, then you might want to use the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion initializer so that your database is updated automatically on startup.

Comment: You may alternatively decide to generate a .sql script from your code migrations (using the update-database -script command) and running the .sql script manually. It depends on the type of app you're creating and your deployment model.

Comment: well indeed, if the database does not exists, with the line `Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<BlogContext, Configuration>());` and **no configuration**, migration (and `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;`), the database is created and migrated but the initial configuration is not applied (length = 128 for name).