# Entity framework many-to-many relation table created "backwards"

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, eager-loading

I'm having an issue with EF6 and many-to-many relations. I have a following setup:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubBar> SubBars { get; set; }

    public Foo()
    {
        Bars = new HashSet<Bar>();
        SubBars = new HashSet<SubBar>();
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

    public Bar()
    {
        Foos = new HashSet<Foo>();
    }
}

public class SubBar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

    public SubBar()
    {
        Foos = new HashSet<Foo>();
    }
}
```

The relation between `Foo` and `Bar` works properly, and there is a table called `BarFoos` in the DB. However the relation between `Foo` and `SubBar` is reversed. There is a table in the DB called `FooSubBars` which basically holds the correct relations, but eager loading, like `SubBar.AsQueryable().Include(sb => sb.Foos)` returns an `EntityCommandExecutionException` with a message `Invalid object name dbo.SubBarFoos`.

Question is: How do I reverse the relation table name to allow eager loading?

--Edit--
DB creation in the migration is as follows:

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.BarFoos",
            c => new
                {
                    Bar_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Foo_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.Bar_Id, t.Foo_Id })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Bars", t => t.Bar_Id, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Foos", t => t.Foo_Id, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.Bar_Id)
            .Index(t => t.Foo_Id);

CreateTable(
            "dbo.FooSubBars",
            c => new
                {
                    Foo_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    SubBar_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.Foo_Id, t.SubBar_Id })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Foos", t => t.Foo_Id, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.SubBars", t => t.SubBar_Id, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.Foo_Id)
            .Index(t => t.SubBar_Id);
```

Would replacing the table name in the migration be sufficient?

Comment: How do you have those relationships mapped? I'm assuming you're using Code First from the fact that the database table is "created backwards".

Comment: Yes, I'm using code-first. By mapping, do you mean the code in the migration file?

Comment: do you have somewhere something like `modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().HasMany(x => x.SubBars).WithMany(y => y.Foos)`, or `modelBuilder.Entity<SubBar>().HasMany(x => x.Foos).WithMany(y => y.SubBars)` (one is enough)

Comment: Nope. Does EF just 'guess' the order of the relation and it works in the first example By pure luck or does it have something to do with the order the types are declared or something?

Comment: And Intellisense finds the child collection as it should. The conflict in the table name seems to be the only problem.

Comment: you should (indeed must ?) have an override of your DbContext.OnModelCreating somewhere in your code. The tables names are not the problem. It is the relational model.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805394/what-is-the-difference-between-entitytypeconfiguration-and-dbmigration-for-a-new

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ensure the table name is generated as "FooBars" if you override the OnModelCreating method on your DbContext as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().HasMany(f => f.Bars).WithMany(b => b.Foos)
            .Map(m => 
                m.ToTable("FooBars")
                // Optionally specify the key column names...
                .MapLeftKey("FooId") 
                .MapRightKey("BarId")
            );

    modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().HasMany(f => f.SubBars).WithMany(sb => sb.Foos).Map(m => m.ToTable("FooSubBars"));
}
```

Which will produce this in the migration:

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.FooBar",
            c => new
                {
                    FooId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    BarId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.FooId, t.BarId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Foos", t => t.FooId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Bars", t => t.BarId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.FooId)
            .Index(t => t.BarId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.FooSubBar",
            c => new
                {
                    Foo_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    SubBar_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.Foo_Id, t.SubBar_Id })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Foos", t => t.Foo_Id, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.SubBars", t => t.SubBar_Id, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.Foo_Id)
            .Index(t => t.SubBar_Id);
```

I also tried eager loading the Foos when querying SubBars on the DbContext with don't get any errors:

```
var context = new FooBarContext();

var subBars = from sb in context.SubBars.Include(i => i.Foos)
              select sb;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reverse the naming by checking here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591620(v=vs.113).aspx

So long as both Entity1 and Entity2 have navagational properties to eachother, then the following works.

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                .HasMany(t => t.Products)
                .WithMany(t => t.Orders);
```

which produces

```
            CreateTable(
            "dbo.OrderProducts",
            c => new
                {
                    Order_OrderID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Product_ID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.Order_OrderID, t.Product_ID })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Orders", t => t.Order_OrderID, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Products", t => t.Product_ID, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.Order_OrderID)
            .Index(t => t.Product_ID);
```