# Entity Framework bug with table name when add entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have table **BookComments** and **FileComments**. I have entity class **BookComment** and **FileComment**.

When I get data everything is fine. But when I try add data, I get error. Not find **BooksComments** table or **FilesComments**. I try use TableAttribute class but didn't help me.

I use Entity Framework 6.1.3

**Update**

If I rename table name from **BookComments** to **BooksComment**. I can't get data and get error

> Invalid object name dbo.BookComments

Add entity

```
    public void AddEntity(T entity)
    {
        this.Entities.Add(entity);
    }

    protected IDbSet<T> Entities
    {
            get
            {
                return this._entities ?? (this._entities = this._context.Set<T>());
            }
```

**Add comment Book controller class**

```
 public async Task<JsonResult> AddComment(int id, Comment comment)
        {
            try
            {
                CommentItem addComment = await Task.Run(() =>
                        {
                            var newcomment = this._booksService.AddComment(id, comment);
                            return AutoMapManager.GetMap<CommentItem, IComment>(newcomment);
                        });

                return this.Json(new { Result = true, comment = addComment }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return this.Json(new { Result = false, e.GetBaseException().Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        }
```

**BookService class**

```
 public IComment AddComment<T>(int bookId, T item) where T : new()
    {
        var comment = AutoMapManager.GetMap<BookComment, T>(item);
        comment.BookId = bookId;

        this._commentRepository.AddEntity(comment);
        this._commentRepository.SaveChanges();
        return comment;
    }
```

Comment: Arw there 2 typos or does the error really say BooksComments and FilesComments? If so, the problem is quite obvious. Like you said, your tables are BookComments (not BooksComments) and FileCommemts (not FilesComments). See this my question for naming tables in EF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30101272/entity-framework-many-to-many-relation-table-created-backwards

Comment: How I saw I can get data, only problems with add new data. And if I renamed table name to BooksComments. I can read data and get error Invalid object name dbo.BookComments

Comment: The problem is propably with your object model. Post your code from the classes and your insert and get methods.

Comment: I use generic repository, also I have ArticleComments and I haven't problem. And I found new problems. I have Forum and namespace is SGN.Modules.Forums.Entities. But when I try get data I get error. Because EF try get Forum entity in SGN.Core

Comment: Post your code. Hard to guess where the problem is without seeing it.

Comment: I posted code. But I thinking this problem with EF

Answer (score 0):

Check to ensure your table names in SQL have the same case sensitivity as your model.  The entity framework uses SQL (which is usually case insensitive) for queries ... which is why you can retrieve data.  But when you add rows, EF is using the CLR (which is case sensitive) to find the table entity.  See if that is your issue first.